# How to clone an iterator?

Tags: scala, iterator

Suppose I have an iterator:

```
val it = List("a","b","c").iterator
```

I want a copy of it; my code is:

```
val it2 = it.toList.iterator
```

It's correct, but seems not good. Is there any other API to do it?

Comment: Why?  Once you've cloned it the original iterator will be consumed and useless, thus defeating the whole point of a clone in the first place...

Comment: @Kevin, that's not necessarily the case, surely? Abstractly, it would seem possible to have an operation that gives me an iterator that will return the same sequence as the source iterator would - of course, issues of state might make it impossible for all iterators. It doesn't seem to inherently require consuming the source one.

Comment: Switching from `val` to `def` would give you a new iterator every time you reference the symbol (named `it` in the above example). In many cases this way may feel simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Warning: as of Scala 2.9.0, at least, this leaves the original iterator empty.  You can* `val ls = it.toList; val it1 = ls.iterator; val it2 = ls.iterator` *to get two copies.  Or use duplicate (which works for non-lists also).*

Rex's answer is by the book, but in fact your original solution is by far the most efficient for scala.collection.immutable.List's.

List iterators can be duplicated using that mechanism with essentially no overhead. This can be confirmed by a quick review of the implementation of iterator() in scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq, esp. the definition of the toList method, which simply returns the _.toList of the backing Seq which, if it's a List (as it is in your case) is the identity.

I wasn't aware of this property of List iterators before investigating your question, and I'm very grateful for the information ... amongst other things it means that many "list pebbling" algorithms can be implemented efficiently over Scala immutable Lists using Iterators as the pebbles.

Comment: I wish I could favorite comments as well as questions, because you raise an excellent use case/point.

Comment: related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380592/spec2-breaks-my-test-data-due-to-the-way-it-works-with-iterator

Answer (score 19):

The method you are looking for is `duplicate`.

```
scala> val it = List("a","b","c").iterator
it: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val (it1,it2) = it.duplicate
it1: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator
it2: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator

scala> it1.length
res11: Int = 3

scala> it2.mkString
res12: String = abc
```

Comment: Warning: this uses a mutable `Queue` to cache the difference between the iterators, which might lead to unexpected memory problems. Also, `next` and `hasNext` are `synchronized` for the new iterators, which make them much slower than normal iterators.

Comment: Another warning: While `it1` and `it2` can be used independently, calling `it.next` forwards both of the duplicates! Also, the duplicates start at `it`'s current element, not the list's beginning. `duplicate` is especially badly documented, sadly.

Comment: Warnings granted.  They're important to realize, but also are "self evident" if you think carefully about what you're asking for: of course, if you have one iterator and you want two that aren't in sync, you're going to need some sort of storage, you can only start at where you are and not go back to a lost beginning, and if you're not just going to copy _everything_ then you'll need synchronization in order to figure out what has been left behind by both iterators and what is ready to grab.

Comment: @Rex Kerr, Just a question, can I reassign one of the duplicate iterators to the original iterator and carry on using the original one from then on ? val(it1,it2) = it.duplicate it = it1 println(it.length) println(it2.mkString)

Comment: @HaseebJaved - Why not?  You're just saying that `it` now refers to the same stuff that `it1` did.