# How to copy iterator in Scala?

Tags: scala, iterator

### About duplicate

*This is NOT a duplicate of [How to clone an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220108/a-very-simple-question-how-to-clone-an-iterator)*

Please do not blindly close this question, all the answers given in so-called duplicate **DO NOT** work. The OP is in charge of the other problem, and obviously, the answers fitted HIS problem, but not mine.

Not every similar question is a duplicate, there is such feature as "expansion question" on SE, the only way is to ask again on the same subject to get different, working, answers.

### Problem

I have iterator. I would like to get copy (duplicate) of it, so then I could proceed with original and copy completely independently.

**Important**

Copying through reflection or serialization is no-go (performance penalty).

**Example**

```
var list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
var it1 = list.iterator
it1.next()

var it2 = it1   // (*)
it2.next()

println(it1.next())
```

This would make simply reference to **it1**, so when changing **it1**, **it2** changes as well and vice-versa.

*The example above uses **List**, I am currently struggling with **HashMap**, but the question is general one -- just iterator.*

#### Approach #1

If you edit line (*) and write:

```
var it2 = it1.toList.iterator
```

(this was suggested as solution in the linked question) the exception is thrown while executing the program.

#### Approach #2

"You take the list and...". No, I don't. I don't have a list, I have iterator. In general I don't know anything about collection which underlies the iterator, the only thing I have is iterator. I have to "fork" it.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Use my answer for the other question; it works in all cases.  (The method is also called `duplicate`.)

Comment: I have edited Miles' answer on the other page to highlight that what you tried to do here will not work and give a working solution.

Comment: @Rex Kerr, no, it is not duplicate judging by answers. The answers given in the other question answers the OTHER question and they DO NOT fit my question. I appreciate your answers, they are educational and for sure I know more, but they don't solve THIS problem.

Comment: You can't even assume an iterator is backed by a collection.  Assume that the thing behind the iterator is something like a video card.  hasNext always returns true, and next returns the next available screenshot.  What would it mean to "copy" that iterator?  What would it mean to duplicate it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't duplicate an iterator without destroying it.  The contract for `iterator` is that it can only be traversed once.

The question you linked to shows how to get two copies in exchange for the one you've destroyed.  You cannot keep using the original, but you can now run the two new copies forward independently.

Comment: Is there guarantee (by language) this would work for iterator for any collection? However, with such approach I will run into problems anyway -- I have two loops for example, and I have to start at next point in the nested loop, when the main iterator is, but I cannot destroy it.

Comment: It is guaranteed to work for any iterator.  Refactor your outer loop to update its iterator.  Alternatively, convert your iterator into a stream and do everything with streams.

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty easy to create a `List` iterator that you can duplicate without destroying it: this is basically the definition of the `iterator` method copied from the `List` source with a `fork` method added:

```
class ForkableIterator[A] (list: List[A]) extends Iterator[A] {
    var these = list
    def hasNext: Boolean = !these.isEmpty
    def next: A = 
      if (hasNext) {
        val result = these.head; these = these.tail; result
      } else Iterator.empty.next
    def fork = new ForkableIterator(these)
}
```

Use:

```
scala> val it = new ForkableIterator(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))
it: ForkableIterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> it.next
res72: Int = 1

scala> val it2 = it.fork
it2: ForkableIterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> it2.next
res73: Int = 2

scala> it2.next
res74: Int = 3

scala> it.next
res75: Int = 2
```

I had a look at doing this for `HashMap` but it seems more complicated (partly because there are different map implementations depending on collection size). So probably best to use the above implementation on `yourMap.toList`.

Comment: @macias It's more than educational. I did a benchmark, and found this is **12 times** faster than using `duplicate`, and 29% faster than `toList` followed by creating 2 new iterators on that list. In short, never use `duplicate` where performance is important. (The 29% figure will be an under-estimate of the actual speed improvement of `ForkableIterator`, because the benchmark does not measure the iterator duplication alone.)

Comment: The sense of iterator, how I understand it, is to traverse data on demand. For example when we read data from file. Like:  val iterator:Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines(). But in this example/asnwer we feed this iterator by already filled List (which could consume a lot of memory). That's not one (me) might want to get from iterator. Then better use List itself.

Answer (score 6):

As Rex said, it is impossible to make a copy of an Iterator without destroying it. That said, what is the problem with `duplicate`?

```
var list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
var it1 = list.iterator
it1.next()

val (it1a, it1b) = it1.duplicate
it1 = it1a
var it2 = it1b
it2.next()

println(it1.next())
```

Comment: One problem could be that this is inefficient if you're duplicating every loop; you end up with a giant chain of garbage that you can't throw away.

Comment: Ah, Daniel, you already posted the list of the problems with **duplicate** :-).

Comment: I find the `duplicate` idiom clumsy. I could fairly imagine, instead, something like `val it2 = it1.clone`

Comment: @matt I assume you expect both `it1` and `it2` to be usable? It is impossible to implement that. Feel free to try to implement, and I'll give you examples of how your code is broken.

Comment: Yes I guess to "clone" you need to iterate, hence you deplete the original copy...

Comment: Related is [this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4943) about this code:
`import scala.io.Source;
val iter = Source.fromFile("tests/1.7m-lines").getLines;
val (a, b) = iter.duplicate;
for (l <- a) { println(l.trim.toLowerCase.replaceAll("_", "
").replaceAll("\\|", " ")); }
// do something else with b`
which uses > 600mb of live memory

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki Bad OOP, really. `duplicate` could be overridden in many places to make it smarter, but it just never is.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very good question, it's a pity that many one doesn't understood the value of the problem. In the age of Big Data there are a lot of situation that we have a stream, not an allocated list of the data that cannot be collected or fit into memory. And the repeating of it from the very begin is costly too. What we can do if we need two (or more) separate calculation with the data? For example we may need to calculate min, max, sum, md5 etc using already written functions with only one pass through in the different threads.

The general solution is to use Akka-Stream. This will do it.
But is it possible with Iterator, that is the easiest way in Java/Scala to represent such streaming data source?
The answer is yes, although we "could NOT proceed with original and copy completely independently" in meaning that we have to synchronize the speeds of consumption of each consumer thread. (Akka-Stream do this leveraging using back-pressure and some intermediate buffers).

So here is my easy solution: to use Phaser. With it we can make Iterator wrapper  over one-pass source. This object are to use in each consumer thread as simple Iterator. Using it you are to know the number of consuming threads in advance. Also each consumer-thread MUST drain the source until the end to avoid the hang of all overs (using flush() method for example).

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

// it0 - input source iterator
// num - exact number of consuming threads. We have to know it in advance.
case class ForkableIterator[+A]( it0: Iterator[A], num: Int ) extends Phaser(num) with Iterator[A] {

  val it = it0.flatMap( Stream.fill(num)(_) )  // serial replicator

  private var hasNext0 = new AtomicBoolean( it0.hasNext )
  override def hasNext: Boolean = hasNext0.get()

  override def next(): A = {
    arriveAndAwaitAdvance()
    val next = it.synchronized {
      val next = it.next()
      if (hasNext0.get) hasNext0.set(it.hasNext)
      next
    }
    arriveAndAwaitAdvance() // otherwise the tasks locks at the end the last data element
    next
  }

  // In case that a consumer gives up to read before the end of its source data stream occurs
  // it HAVE to drain the last to avoid block others. (Note: Phaser has no "unregister" method?).
  // Calling it may be avoided if all consumers read exactly the same amount of data,
  // e.g. until the very end of it.
  def flush(): Unit = while (hasNext) next()
}
```

PS This "ForkableIterator" was successfully used by me with Spark to perform several independent aggregations over long stream of source data. In such case I have no bother about creating threads manually. You may also use Scala Futures / Monix Tasks etc.

PSPS I recheck the JDK Phaser specification now and find that It actually has "unregister" method called arriveAndDeregister(). So use it instead of flush() if a consumer complete.