# How to make atomic exchange -- Scala way?

Tags: multithreading, scala, atomic

### Problem

I have such code

```
var ls = src.iter.toList
src.iter = ls.iterator
```

(this is part of copy constructor of my iterator-wrapper) which reads the source iterator, and in next line set it back. The problem is, those two lines have to be atomic (especially if you consider that I change the source of copy constructor -- I don't like it, but well...).

I've read about Actors but I don't see how they fit here -- they look more like a mechanism for asynchronous execution. I've read about Java solutions and using them in Scala, for example: http://naedyr.blogspot.com/2011/03/atomic-scala.html

My question is: what is the most Scala way to make some operations atomic? I don't want to use some heavy artillery for this, and also I would not like to use some external resources. In other words -- something that looks and feels "right".

I kind like the solution presented in the above link, because this is what I exactly do -- exchange references. And if I understand correctly, I would guard only those 2 lines, and other code does not have to be altered! But I will wait for definitive answer.

### Background

Because every Nth question, instead of answer I read "but why do you use...", here:
[How to copy iterator in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797990/how-to-copy-iterator-in-scala) :-)

I need to copy iterator (make a fork) and such solution is the most "right" I read about. The problem is, it destroys the original iterator.

#### Solutions

**Locks**

For example here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala02049/index.html

The only problem I see here, that I have to put lock on those two lines, and every other usage on iter. It is minor thing now, but when I add some code, it is easy to forget to add additional lock.

I am not saying "no", but I have no experience, so I would like to get answer from someone who is familiar with Scala, to point a direction -- which solution is the best for such task, and in long-run.

**Immutable iterator**

While I appreciate the explanation by Paradigmatic, I don't see how such approach fits my problem. The thing is IteratorWrapper class has to wrap iterator -- i.e. raw iterator should be hidden within the class (usually it is done by making it private). Such methods as hasNext() and next() should be wrapped as well. Normally next() alters the state of the object (iterator) so in case of immutable IteratorWrapper it should return both new IteratorWrapper and status of next() (successful or not). Another solution would be returning NULL if raw next() fails, anyway, this makes using such IteratorWrapper not very handy.

Worse, there is still not easy way to copy such IteratorWrapper.

So either I miss something, or actually classic approach with making piece of code atomic is cleaner. Because all the burden is contained inside the class, and the user does not have to pay the price of they way IteratorWrapper handles the data (raw iterator in this case).

Comment: Why don't you use a lock? That would be atomic.

Comment: You mean lock similar to C# lock? (I am asking because I am just starting with Scala) -- well, that's why I am asking :-) But if this is similar to C#, this would mean I would have to add locks in every piece that uses "iter" member. Once I forgot about it, I would have problems. I am not saying "no", I am just thinking aloud.

Comment: Why don't you restrict direct access to `src.iter`, and access it only using methods that do the locking?

Comment: You mean by private? Of course I did, it is a private member of the class, but within the class it can be changed (for example by another copy constructor). About locking -- is this is the best solution for this problem (for example vs. compare-and-exchange)? If yes -- ok.

Comment: There's always the STM support in Akka, that should give you the atomic characteristics you're seeking.

Comment: @macias It may be better than devising you own mini-lock-free atomic algorithm, but this depends on the use-case - for example, how often you access the field to convert the iterator into a list, and how big the list is.

Comment: @axel22, it is supposed to be general library of mine; current project -- iterator will go over 100K+ elements, and each step the copy will happen.

Comment: @Kevin Wright, this looks great, could you please post an answer, not just comment, thank you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala approach is to favor immutability whenever it is possible (and it's very often possible). Then you do not need anymore copy constructors, locks, mutex, etc.

For example, you can convert the iterator to a `List` at object construction. Since lists are immutable, you can safely share them without having to lock:

```
class IteratorWrapper[A]( iter: Iterator[A] ) {
  val list = iter.toList

  def iteratorCopy = list.iterator
}
```

Here, the `IteratorWrapper` is also immutable. You can safely pass it around. But if you really need to change the wrapped iterator, you will need more demanding approaches. For instance you could:

1. Use locks
2. Transform the wrapper into an `Actor`
3. Use STM (akka or other implementations).

---

**Clarifications:** I lack information on your problem constraints. But here is how I understand it.

Several threads must traverse simultaneously an `Iterator`. A possible approach is to copy it before passing the reference to the threads. However, Scala practice aims at sharing immutable objects that do not need to be copied.

With the copy strategy, you would write something like:

```
//A single iterator producer
class Producer {
  val iterator: Iterator[Foo] = produceIterator(...)
}

//Several consumers, living on different threads
class Consumer( p: Producer ) {
  def consumeIterator = {
    val iteratorCopy = copy( p.iterator ) //BROKEN !!!
    while( iteratorCopy.hasNext ) {
      doSomething( iteratorCopy.next )
    } 
  }  
}
```

However, it is difficult (or slow) to implement a copy method which is thread-safe. A possible solution using immutability will be:

```
class Producer {
  val lst: List[Foo] = produceIterator(...).toList 
  def iteratorCopy = list.iterator
}

class Consumer( p: Producer ) {
  def consumeIterator = {
    val iteratorCopy = p.iteratorCopy 
    while( iteratorCopy.hasNext ) {
      doSomething( iteratorCopy.next )
    } 
  }  
}
```

The producer will call `produceIterator` once at construction. It it immutable because its state is only a list which is also immutable. The `iteratorCopy` is also thread-safe, because the list is not modified when creating the copy (so several thread can traverse it simultaneously without having to lock).

Note that calling `list.iterator` does not traverse the list. So it will not decrease performances in any way (as opposed to really copying the iterator each time).

Comment: Maybe I didn't catch up with Scala yet -- look at your first line, assigning value to "list". Doesn't it iterate over "iter"? Meaning you created IteratorWrapper instance, OK, but from outside POV you just ignored the entire collection. IOW: you didn't make a copy, you "shifted" the content from one place to another.

Comment: 1. The iterator has to be traversed once to build the list. But that will happen only once when the `IteratorWrapper` is instanciated. After construction, you can discard it. 2. The advantage of immutable datastructures is that you can "shift" them without having to make copies. You gain not only thread-safety, but also speed.

Comment: (1) Ok, but then how do I copy IteratorWrapper to another IteratorWrapper? It is exactly my case. I have to start IW-2 from place where IW-1 points at. (2) Or do you mean, that IW should implement next() in such way that not only it should return the value from the collection but also next-itself?

Comment: You'll never need to copy the wrapper ! Since it cannot be modified, there will be no concurrency problems. Different threads can point to the very same `IteratorWrapper` instance. Then, if you want to get a copy of the original iterator, just call `iteratorCopy`.

Comment: No. `next()` is an `Iterator[A]` method which returns an object of type `A`. It is thread safe to pass the wrapped iterator around and copy it (with `iteratorCopy`).

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. Could you please expand your answer, and show the loop with next(), hasNext() with your IteratorWrapper? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I've done it. In the example, the data producer acts as the `IteratorWrapper`.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't get it. As I see your expansion you are doing the iteration using raw iterator instead of IteratorWrapper, this completely kills the idea of IteratorWrapper, because if you use raw iterator, you could drop IteratorWrapper at all. Thank you for your time anyway.