# create n iterators from one iterator

Tags: scala

I wanted to create n iterators from one in scala using 'duplicate'

came up with that code:

```
def getNIterators[T](it: Iterator[T], n: Int) : Seq[Iterator[T]] = {
  getNMoreIterators(Seq(it), n-1)
}

private def getNMoreIterators[T](seq: Seq[Iterator[T]], n: Int) : Seq[Iterator[T]] = {
if (n <= 0) return seq else {
  val (it1, it2) = seq.head.duplicate
  Seq(it1, it2) ++ getNMoreIterators(seq.tail, n-1)
}
}
```

Can I improve it to tailrecurtion or a method that is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually destroying the current `Iterator` and getting 2 new in return. I think it would me more efficient to just destroy `Iterator` once and put it in a `Seq`, getting iterators from there (that's just an intuition, I didn't bemchmark it).

```
def getNIterators[A](it: Iterator[A], n: Int) : Seq[Iterator[A]] = {
  val seq = it.toSeq
  Seq.fill(n)(seq.iterator)
}
```

You might want to read about problems with `duplicate` here: [How to copy iterator in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797990/how-to-copy-iterator-in-scala) and here: [How to clone an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220108/how-to-clone-an-iterator)

### Edit:

Ok then, if you don't want to consume whole iterator in the beginning, consider using a `Stream`

```
def getNIterators[A](it: Iterator[A], n: Int) : Seq[Iterator[A]] = {
  val seq = it.toStream
  Seq.fill(n)(seq.iterator)
}
```

It will consume `Iterator` as needed (except for the head, it will be consumed immidietly), and all the `Iterators` are independent.

```
scala> (1 to 4).iterator.map(s => {println(s); s})
res12: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> getNIterators(res12, 4)
1
res13: Seq[Iterator[Int]] = List(non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator)

scala> res13.map(_.next)
res14: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1)

scala> res13.map(_.next)
2
res15: Seq[Int] = List(2, 2, 2, 2)

scala> res13.map(_.next)
3
res16: Seq[Int] = List(3, 3, 3, 3)

scala> res13.map(_.next)
4
res17: Seq[Int] = List(4, 4, 4, 4)
```

Comment: As far as I understand what you are doing herr is actually consuming the iterator and I don't want to do that

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def getNIterators[T](it: Iterator[T], n: Int) : Seq[Iterator[T]] = {
   (1 to n).map(_ => it.duplicate._2)
}
```

Comment: I dont think you're allowed to call duplicate more than once on the same iterator