# Scala Spark: Duplicating an Iterator

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using the following code but I've read that `iterator.duplicate` is an expensive operation, isn't? Is there a way to use another thing in my code to make it better in performance?

The `myRdd` is `RDD[LabeledPoint]`.
The thing is to try to transform from the RDD[LabeledPoint] to a RDD[(String, Labelepoint)]:

```
var result = List[(String, Labelepoint)]()
var size = 0
var data: LabeledPoint = null
var op = ""
myRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
  { (partID, iterator) => {
    val (iterator1, iterator2) = iterator.duplicate
    size = iterator1.length - 1
    while (iterator2.hasNext) {
      data = iterator2.next
      op = partID + "," + size
      result ::= (op, data)
      size = size - 1
    }
    result.iterator
  }
  }, preservesPartitioning = true)
```

Comment: Where are `size`, `data`, `op`, and `result` declared? Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I've already added more information to my question. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons that `Iterator.duplicate` is expensive. The first is stated in the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html#duplicate:(Iterator[A],Iterator[A])):

> The implementation may allocate temporary storage for elements iterated by one iterator but not yet by the other.

Indeed, since you call `iterator1.length` at the start, it will need to store all of the elements in memory. This could cause problems if the iterator is extremely large and you're tight on memory.

The second is mentioned by [Daniel C. Sobral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral) in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220424/2093695), and it is that the iterators it creates are synchronized, which slows them down. This can be solved by just using `iterator.toSeq` instead of `iterator.duplicate`, since you're already storing all the elements in memory anyway. Here's an example:

```
myRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
    (partID, iterator) => iterator.toSeq.reverse.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (data, i) => (partID + "," + i, data)
    }.iterator,
    preservesPartitioning = true)
```

If you want to use less memory, that's a bit harder. You're also creating the list `result` that will have the same size, so you would need to fix that too. I don't think it's possible to get the exact behavior you have (including reversing the iterator) without storing all of the elements in memory. That said, if you're okay with having your result and your numbering be in the reverse order from that given in your code, this works with constant memory usage:

```
myRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
    (partID, iterator) => iterator.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (data, i) => (partID + "," + i, data)
    },
    preservesPartitioning = true)
```

Comment: Yes, I don't care the order of the data. So, I'll use the second option.